# how to append a list of lists in Groovy

Tags: groovy

How do I append a list of lists in a purely functional way in groovy? Like if I have a list in variable "a", with a method "b" that returns a list, I can do this:

```
a.*b
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
```

but what I really want is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This would be easy for example in the Scheme programming language:

```
(define foo '((1 2) (3 4 5) (6)))
(apply append foo)
=> (1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

how to do (apply append list-of-lists) in groovy? I know I can do flatten() but that goes arbitrarily deep, and that's not what I want.

Comment: The question begins "How do I append a list of lists in a purely functional way in groovy?" but the rest of the question is talking about something else and an answer below that shows how to append a list of lists in a functional way was commented to show that isn't really what you want.  Consider adding clarity to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code shows the spread-operator.  So instead of using that,
you can use `collectMany`.

If you prefer to build the intermediate result and then "apply" one
function to merge all lists, you can use `sum`, which on an array
concats all elements.

```
def a = [[b:[1]],[b:[2,[3]]]]

println(a.collectMany{ it.b })
// → [1, 2, [3]]

println(a*.b.sum())
// → [1, 2, [3]]
```

Comment: In response to answers that have since been deleted the OP said "Show me the functional code that goes from `[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]` to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`".  Can `collectMany` be used to help with that?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I can see those deleted answers and this is why a added
mine. Both variants do exactly that and they don't remove nesting.

Comment: I believe you and am interested to know how that works.  Can you edit your answer to show how to use `collectMany` to help turn `[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]` into `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`?

Comment: Is it just `[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]].collectMany { it }`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown `[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]].collectMany{it}` or `[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]].sum()`

Comment: `collectMany` sadly has no zero arity with an identity default (like e.g. `collectEntries` has)

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, we have a winner. So there are two answers, either [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]].sum() or [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]].collectMany { it }, and if I'm using the spread operataor, the easiest is a.*b.sum() or a.collectMany { it.b }. Nice!

Comment: @emilles OP stated in the question, they don't want to use flatten.